# Draw pixel by pixel on Custom Renderer (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, drawing, custom-renderer

I have a frame with some items inside. The corner is very useful, but is there a way to draw pixel by pixel, or shapes using Custom Renderers?

I'm trying to draw a message balloon.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be using [SkiaSharp](https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-2d-graphics-with-skiasharp/), which would allow you to have all your drawing code in your pcl/shared library.

Another option would be to create a custom view and write custom renderers for each platform, which add a native drawing canvas to your Forms view and do all the drawing procedures you need. It might be a bit faster than Skia in terms of performance, however the downside is that you have to write dedicated drawing code for each platform involved.

As of my personal experience, I'd suggest using Skia, especially if you intend to alter the drawings depending on data or user input.